# Detecting if a sprite's color is not the color of another sprite

Tags: swift, colors, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

So I have this sprite kit game, which is coded in swift 2. The game includes these colored circles (Green, Red, Purple, Yellow, Blue) that fall down the screen, starting from the same height, but starting at different widths. At the bottom of the screen there is a bar that tells you what color NOT to press. So if the bar is yellow, and you click a yellow circle, you lose. I already have the losing implementation, but I can't seem to figure out how to detect if the circle clicked is not the color on the bar. Here is my code on the color detection. Keep in mind, the variable "colorNeeded" is the color that you do not want to click

```
switch colorNeeded  {
    case SKColor.redColor():
        if Red.containsPoint(location)   {
            print("Color Needed is Blue, Blue Circle Clicked")
            print("Lose, score is: \(score)")
            changeColorNeeded()
        }
        break

    case SKColor.blueColor():
        if Blue.containsPoint(location)   {
            print("Color Needed is Blue, Blue Circle Clicked")
            print("Lose, score is: \(score)")
            changeColorNeeded()
        }
        break

    case SKColor.yellowColor():
        if Yellow.containsPoint(location)   {
            print("Color Needed is Blue, Blue Circle Clicked")
            print("Lose, score is: \(score)")
            changeColorNeeded()
        }
        break

    case SKColor.greenColor():
         if Green.containsPoint(location)   {
             print("Color Needed is Blue, Blue Circle Clicked")
             print("Lose, score is: \(score)")
             changeColorNeeded()
         }
         break

    case SKColor.purpleColor():
         if Purple.containsPoint(location)   {
             print("Color Needed is Blue, Blue Circle Clicked")
             print("Lose, score is: \(score)")
             changeColorNeeded()
         }
         break

    default:
        if Purple.containsPoint(location) || Green.containsPoint(location) || Yellow.containsPoint(location) || Blue.containsPoint(location) || Red.containsPoint(location){
            score++
            ("Good Color Clicked")
            ChangeCounter++
            if ChangeCounter == 5 {
                changeColorNeeded()
            }
        }
        break  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an `else` to your `if` statements, that either sets a flag indicating that you did not click the wrong color, or calls a method that has the code in the `default`'s `if` statement.  Something like this:

This is false until proven positive:

```
var isSafeClick = false

case SKColor.redColor():

    if Red.containsPoint(location)   {

        print("Color Needed is Blue, Blue Circle Clicked")
        print("Lose, score is: \(score)")
        changeColorNeeded()
    } else {
        isSafeClick = true
    }

    break
```

Etc. for each `if` statement in the switch.  At the end of the `switch` statement, add in another `if` to see if the `isSafeClick` is `true`:

```
if (isSafeClick) {
    score++
    ("Good Color Clicked")
    ChangeCounter++
    if ChangeCounter == 5{
        changeColorNeeded()
    }
}
```

For the method way, just put the code directly above this text into a method (named something like "safeScorePoint" or whatever), and in the `else` of each `if/else` call that method.

Comment: I was not aware that switch statements had an else. Thanks

Comment: The switch statement doesn't, the `if` statement that you were using _inside_ the `case` can have an `else`.  You're welcome!